# Manipulation Parameters with Conditions

Tags: manipulate

I have a list, and length of this list can be changed sometimes. I want to define manipulation parameters inside "Manipulate" according to length of the list.

For example:

```
list={1,2,3,4};
Manipulate[
Row[{
Which[
  Length[list] == 1, Control@{{n1, 1, "a"}, 0, 9, 1},
  Length[list] == 2, (Control@{{n1, 1, "a"}, 0, 9, 1},
                      Control@{{n2, 5, "b"}, 1, 2, 0.1})
  ]
}]
]
```

Comment: Hi Valinor, welcome to Mma.SE. Start by **taking the [tour] now** and learning about [asking](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O) and what's [on-topic](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O). Always [edit] if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context. Thanks for your minimal working example and code in [formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX). By doing all this you help us to help you and likely you will inspire great answers. The site depends on participation, as you receive **give back:** vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 4};

Attributes[Manipulate]

(* {HoldAll, Protected, ReadProtected} *)
```

There are multiple problems with your code. Since the [`Attributes`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Attributes.html) for [`Manipulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) include [`HoldAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAll.html), you must [`Evaluate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html) the [`Which`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Which.html) for the controls to be seen as such. At least one of the tests of the `Which` must be satisfied. The default for the controls must fall within the ranges specified for the controls. The `Manipulate` must include an expression prior to the control(s). Parentheses cannot be used to hold a [`Sequence`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sequence.html).

```
Manipulate[
 list,
 Row[{
   Evaluate@
    Which[
     Length[list] == 1, Control@{{n1, 1, "a"}, 0, 9, 1,
       Appearance -> "Labeled"},
     Length[list] > 1, Sequence @@ {
       Control@{{n1, 1, "a"}, 0, 9, 1,
         Appearance -> "Labeled"},
       Control@{{n2, 5, "b"}, 1, 5, 0.1,
         Appearance -> "Labeled"}}]}]]
```

[image]

You could also use [`If`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/If.html)

```
Manipulate[
 list,
 Row[{
   Control@{{n1, 1, "a"}, 0, 9, 1,
     Appearance -> "Labeled"},
   Evaluate@If[Length[list] > 1,
     Control@{{n2, 5, "b"}, 1, 5, 0.1,
       Appearance -> "Labeled"},
     Nothing]}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Bob Hanion. The answer was very helpful. But I have still some error. I am writing may code part which interested with MAnipulate. Thanks for the answers.

```
In[12]:= symbol = {"a", "b", "c"}

Out[12]= {"a", "b", "c"}

In[13]:= value = {1, 2, 3}

Out[13]= {1, 2, 3}

In[19]:= Manipulate[value,

 Row[{
   Text[Style["-------- FIT MANIPULATION --------", FontSize -> 30, 
     Bold, Black]], "\n\n",
   Evaluate@Which[
     Length[value] == 1, 
     Control@{{n1, value[[1]], symbol[[1]]}, -3, 1, 0.1, 
       Appearance -> "Labeled"},
     Length[value] == 2, Sequence @@ {

       Control@{{n1, value[[1]], symbol[[1]]}, -3, 1, 0.1, 
         Appearance -> "Labeled"},

       Control@{{n2, value[[2]], symbol[[2]]}, -7, 1, 0.1, 
         Appearance -> "Labeled"}  },
     Length[value] == 3, Sequence @@ {

       Control@{{n1, value[[1]], symbol[[1]]}, -3, 1, 0.1, 
         Appearance -> "Labeled"},

       Control@{{n2, value[[2]], symbol[[2]]}, -7, 1, 0.1, 
         Appearance -> "Labeled"},  

       Control@{{n3, value[[3]], symbol[[3]]}, -3, 1, 0.1, 
         Appearance -> "Labeled"}   },
     Length[value] == 4, Sequence @@ {

       Control@{{n1, value[[1]], symbol[[1]]}, -3, 1, 0.1, 
         Appearance -> "Labeled"},

       Control@{{n2, value[[2]], symbol[[2]]}, -7, 1, 0.1, 
         Appearance -> "Labeled"},  

       Control@{{n3, value[[3]], symbol[[3]]}, -3, 1, 0.1, 
         Appearance -> "Labeled"},

       Control@{{n4, value[[4]], symbol[[4]]}, -3, 1, 0.1, 
         Appearance -> "Labeled"}   }
                ](*End of Which*)

   }](*End of Row*)
 ](*End of Manipulate*)
```

[image]